# How to load a html file to memory?

Tags: html, c++, visual-studio, wchar-t

I want to load a html file to memory (in fact a wchar_t string). And this is the code:

```
size_t myGetFileSize(const wchar_t *wcPath)
{
    struct _stat fileinfo;
    _wstat(wcPath, &fileinfo);
    return (fileinfo.st_size);
}
int LoadUtf8FileToString(const wchar_t *wcFilename, wchar_t **wcBuffer)
{
    FILE* file = _wfopen(wcFilename, L"rtS, ccs=UTF-8");
    if (file == NULL)
        return (0);
    size_t filesize = myGetFileSize(wcFilename);
    if (filesize > 0)
    {
        *wcBuffer = (wchar_t*) malloc(filesize * sizeof(wchar_t));
        size_t nRead = fread(*wcBuffer, sizeof(wchar_t), filesize, file);
        realloc(*wcBuffer, nRead * sizeof(wchar_t));
    }
    fclose(file);
    return(1);
}
```

And when I navigate it to a iwebbrowser2, it show all page and 4 empty square at the end of page! 
I googled and find a string class called wstring, and using it like this way:

```
std::wstring wString;
/////////////////////
wString->resize(filesize);
size_t wchars_read = fread(&(wString->front()), sizeof(wchar_t), filesize, file);
wString->resize(wchars_read);
wString->shrink_to_fit();
```

and navigate it to iwebbrower2, everythings will be OK! But I don't like to use any class in my program! 
So, What is wrong with my code, please?

Comment: `realloc` may not re-use the same starting address. You throw it away. (Unsure if this is "the" problem - what does "it show all page and 4 empty square at the end of page" mean?)

Comment: *Why* do you reallocate? The buffer is allocated after the file-size, and unless there's an error reading that's the size that `fread` will read, so `realloc` may be a no-op.

Comment: 4 empty squres are unknown characters like these squares: [][][][]

Comment: I've used realloc(), because filesize is greater than readed number!

Comment: *Then* I'd say it is an invalid HTML page, at least by the standard, well ok which one ...

Comment: I used wchar_t because I want to load unicode pages.

Comment: UTF8 can be stored in `char`-arrays.

Comment: Could UTF8 loaded to char, show strings in rtl and ltr languages?

Comment: @Shaheen How a UTF8 string is stored in terms of variable types, and how a UTF8 string is drawn to the screen, are two completely different things. => Yes, UTF8 in char arrays can be displayed in both directions, if the drawing part can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to forget two things: One is that that [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) is a *variable-length* encoding, a character may be one byte, or it may be six bytes. You can't read it as a fixed-width encoding. The other thing you forget is that the size of the file you get is not the number of characters in the file, it's the number of *bytes* in the file.

In fact, if you're reading a HTML-file, odds are quite a lot of the text *are* single bytes, namely all the markup.

In short, the file doesn't contain `filesize` *characters*, it contains `filesize` *bytes*. And you try to read `sizeof(wchar_t) * filesize` bytes, which is why the `fread` call will return the "wrong" size.

Comment: So, I should parse html to load it to memory, and It's not easy. Is there any other way?

Comment: @Shaheen Just read `filesize` *bytes* into the memory, which should be `filesize` *bytes* large. The actual content of the file doesn't matter for the reading and storing into memory.

Comment: Thanx. I should try it!

Answer (score 0):

1. The `realloc` is totally obsolete. You initialize the correct amount of memory (not really, see next) and the number of bytes read can only differ if `fread` somehow fails and reads *less* characters. Then again, even if it does and you shrink (!) your allocated buffer, you forget to update the pointer, so it will still *point to* the original memory block. Which actually gets freed by the `realloc`. You may be getting away with this Undefined Behavior because (apparently) either the memory block is resized in-place, or because `realloc` determines resizing is not necessary.
2. You are getting random characters at the end of your string because *it is a string*, and you do not allocate enough space for a terminating Zero, nor are you writing it.
3. `filesize` is in bytes. Thus allocate and read in *bytes*, not in `wchar_t` units.